# Can you use SVGs in AMP web pages?

Tags: svg, amp-html

Can you use SVGs in AMP web pages?

Can you use them with the amp-img tag's src attribute?

Can you use inline SVGs?

Comment: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec#svg - That was a fairly easy Google search.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**1. Can you use SVGs in AMP web pages?**

Yes you can, for more information  [**Click Here**](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec#svg)

**2. Can you use them with the amp-img tag's src attribute?**

Yes you can example below

```
 <amp-img width="110" height="35" layout="responsive" src="logo.svg"></amp-img>
```

**3. Can you use inline SVGs?**

Yes you can example below

```
 <svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
```